# Sharepoint Online JSON Add Current User to Person Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

SharePoint Online:

I suspect the answer is no, but is there any possibility of using JSON to add the current user by default to a person column in the New Form, in a Modern list?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot add current user as a default value to person column in the list forms using JSON formatting.

You have to customize list forms using Power Apps to set default value of person column in the list forms.

More information and formula to use in Power Apps at:

1. [Set current user as default value of Person or Group field](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Set-current-user-as-default-value-of-Person-or-Group-field/td-p/78744)

Comment: I suspected so.  Thank you again, Ganesh-

Comment: Additional Info: You can set value to person column from list view using button click and `setValue`. Check this sample: https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/master/column-samples/generic-like-unlike/generic-like-unlike.json